# Solving $\sin x = 0$, I get $x=k\times 360^\circ$ and $x=k\times 360^\circ+180^\circ$, but the answer is $x=k\times 180^\circ$.

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $\sin x = 0$ when $x = k\times180^\circ$?

I tried doing it, but I got these results:
$$x=k\times 360^\circ \qquad x=k\times 360^\circ+180^\circ$$

Comment: Those two answers can be “compressed” into one: $x = \pi n$.

Comment: For one way to "see" what @KM101 said, try writing out all values that $k \times 180$ represent in one list, and all values that $k \times 360 + 180$ represent in another list, and then make a combined list of everything that shows up in at least one of the first two lists. Make sure you include negative integer values of $k$ when you do this. (Ah ... I see that KM101 was in the middle of doing eactly this when I was writing my comment!)

Comment: @KM101 how exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I’ve added a rather brief explanation with the list. The idea can be applied in both degrees and radians.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x = 0$$

For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x = \pi + 2\pi n$ OR $x = 2\pi n$.

$$x = \pi + 2\pi n \implies x = …, -5\pi, -3\pi, -\pi,\pi, 3\pi, 5\pi, …$$

$$x = 2\pi n \implies x = …, -6\pi, -4\pi, -2\pi, 0, 2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi, …$$

If you noticed, combining them would give all integer multiples of $\pi$, so you just combine them.
$$x = \pi n$$

You could demonstrate the same idea in degrees: $x = 180+360n$ and $x = 360n$ can be combined to give $x = 180n$.